# flutter radio button from api

Tags: flutter, dart, radio-button

I have been able to display API data from the future builder. However, the widget has a radio button for each list. Whenever I check on one list, the whole list gets checked. I want help on how to check each list individually and be able to use the data of the selected radio button.

```
enter code here
```

else if (_questionmodel
?.data.json[0][index].type ==
"radio-group") ...[
Radio(
value: i,
groupValue: _json?.values[index],
onChanged: (d) {
_json?.values[index] == d;
setState(() {});
print("tapaa kiya ");
},
toggleable: true,
)

```
                                              // buildContainerRadioField1(context, i, index)
                                            ],
```

- 

Comment: post your code here so that we can help you to modify your code.

Comment: you need single and multiple selection at tap on Radio button in list ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are updating the value of the radio button using `_json?.values[index]`. If so, you are not updating the value in the framework. To update the value in the framework use setState.
Here is the updated code,

```
else if (_questionmodel ?.data.json[0][index].type == "radio-group")
 ...[ 
Radio( 
value: i,
groupValue: _json?.values[index],
onChanged: (d) { 

setState(() {
_json?.values[index] == d;
});
print("tapaa kiya ");
},
toggleable: true,
)
```